# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Tags: reactjs

Showing error in the params this.props.match.params.login User.js
In the User class based component, when trying to take value of current user from user object then props not working and shoing error.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    
    export class User extends Component {
        componentDidMount(){
            this.props.getUser(this.props.match.params.login);
            
        }
        
        render() {
            
         const{
                name,
                avatar_url,
                location,
                bio,
                blog,
                login,
                html_url,
                followers,
                following,
                public_repos,
                public_gists,
                hireable,
            } = this.props.user;
            const {loading } = this.props;
        
            return (
                <div>
                    {name}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default User
```

This is App.js here i need to pass props and display the {user}

```
    <Route exact path='/user/:login' element={
                  <User getUser={this.getUser} 
                  user={user} 
                  loading={loading}
                  
                  />
                }>
    </Route>
```

In App.js, there is a function named getUser()

```
    //Get a single github user
      getUser = async (username)=>{
        this.setState({loading:true})
        const res = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}? 
client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`);
        this.setState({user: res.data, loading:false});
    
      }
```

Comment: In `react router dom v6`, no `routeProps` are passed to `element`. you have to use `hooks` to get the location etc. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed `match` as a props to `User` component

```
<Route exact path='/user/:login' element={
              <User getUser={this.getUser} 
              user={user} 
              loading={loading}
              
              />
            }>
</Route>
```